# Pipe each batch of xargs trough wc -l

Tags: linux, find, pipe, xargs

So my task is to find the file with the most hardlinks in  a directory.
So far i have :

```
find . -name "file*" | xargs -I{} -n 1 find . -samefile {}
```

which gives me:

```
./hardlinkFIle245
./hardlinkFIle23
./hardlinkFIle2
./file2.txt
./hardlinkFIle1234
./hardlinkFIle123
./hardlinkFIle12
./hardlinkFIle1
./file1.txt
```

Now when I pipe it in with `|wc -l`, I get the total number of lines 9:

```
find . -name "file*" | xargs -I{} -n 1 find . -samefile {} | wc -l
```

What I want is for each xargs batch -n 1 to give me the count :
so i want:

```
4
5
```

Comment: Doesn't your `find` command's `-printf` have a `%n` specifier for the number of hardlinks? You could simply `sort` and `tail` that

Comment: Thanks man that is the right answer, but the sort is not working as expected after print f: 
find . -printf '%n' | sort -n
How to to sort the answer and also print the file name and sort them by num,ber of hardlinks

Comment: Something like `find . -printf '%n\t%f\n' | sort -n | tail -n 1` *should* work, I think? if there is more than one file with the same number of links, it will return the one whose name is "numerically first"

Comment: The way they are sorted are in order 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4  and so on and not:
just 5 and 4 so tail -n 3 gives me basically 3 5's, since they all point to the same file. But what i want is the  unique files ordered by number by hardlinks sorted so tail - n 2 would give me 5 4  not 5 5.

Comment: Just use uniq command:
find . -printf '%n\n' | uniq | sort -n -r

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using GNU `find`, you can have it report the number of links with `-printf %n`. So you can get the maximum value with:

```
find . -name 'file*' -printf '%n\n' | sort -rn | head -n1
```

Note however that that number may include links that are not found under `.` or for entries that don't match the `file*` pattern.

If you only want to count hardlinks named `file*` found under `.`, and see the paths for those, you could do:

```
find . -name 'file*' -printf '%i\0%p\0' | gawk -v RS='\0' '
   {
     inode = $0
     getline file
   }
   ++count[inode] >= max {
     files[inode] = files[inode] " - " file ORS
     max = count[inode]
     max_inode = inode
   }
   END {
     printf "%s", "File with most links ("max"):\n" files[max_inode]
   }'
```

Which would still run just one `find` invocation instead of one per file.

Answer (score 2):

You can just spawn a new shell on each xargs:

```
find . -name "file*" | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'echo "$1"; find . -samefile "$1" | wc -l' xargs-sh
```

Though using `xargs` is a bad idea here as it would break if file paths contain whitespace of quoting characters.

Here, using `wc -l` is also brittle as it breaks if file paths contain newline characters.

You could use the standard `find -exec cmd {} +` syntax and save having to run one `sh` per file by using a loop:

```
find . -name "file*" -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
    find .//. -samefile "$file" | grep -c //
  done' find-sh {} +
```